# I am using Summernote. Using Jquery focusout() for its div but its not working

Tags: jquery, customization, summernote

I need to run some code when the Summernote div on loses its focus. It is not working properly. Please help.

```
$('#summernote').on('summernote.blur', function(){
    alert('Editable area loses focus');
});
```

Comment: I ran your code and it seems to work, is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/w4vor9sm/

Answer (score 1):

Summernote use it's default classes, in that case I think this way will help also,

```
$(document).find('.summernote').on('summernote.blur', function(){
    alert('Editable area loses focus');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var editor = $('#summernote');
  editor.summernote({
    height: ($(window).height() - 250),
    focus: false,
    toolbar: [
      ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
      ['font', ['strikethrough']],
      ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
      ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
      ['height', ['height']],
      ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],
    ],
    oninit: function() {
      // Add "open" - "save" buttons
      var noteBtn = '<button id="makeSnote" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-small" title="Identify a music note" data-event="something" tabindex="-1"><i class="fa fa-music"></i></button>';
      var fileGroup = '<div class="note-file btn-group">' + noteBtn + '</div>';
      $(fileGroup).appendTo($('.note-toolbar'));
      // Button tooltips
      $('#makeSnote').tooltip({
        container: 'body',
        placement: 'bottom'
      });
      // Button events
      $('#makeSnote').click(function(event) {
        var highlight = window.getSelection(),
          spn = document.createElement('span'),
          range = highlight.getRangeAt(0)

        spn.innerHTML = highlight;
        spn.className = 'snote';
        spn.style.color = 'blue';

        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(spn);
      });
    },

  });


  $(document).find('.summernote').on('summernote.blur', function() {
    alert('Editable area loses focus');
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>







<div style="width: 100%; height: 95px;text-align: center;padding-top: 10px;">
  Outer Area
</div>

<textarea class='summernote' id='summernote' rows='10'></textarea>
```

Comment: `$(document).find('.summernote')` should not be needed since it's not created after the DOM, also how is your code different from the example I gave?